# how to create non-spa website only using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I have a simple test project using react that shows users of fake API. The parent component is named App and it's my home page. There is a button named panel in the App component. I want it to go to Panel Component when I click it.

```
function App() {
const users = useSelector(state => state.users)
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const getUsers=()=>{
        // async action using redux-thunk
        return async function(dispatch){
            try{
            
            dispatch(GetUserRequest())
             const response= await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
             
            
             dispatch(GetUserSuccess(response.data.data))
            }
            catch(er){
                dispatch(GetUserFail(er))
               
            }
        }
    }
useEffect(()=>{
    
   
    dispatch(getUsers())
 }
    
  ,[])
  return (<>
 <Provider store={store}>
 <Routes>
<Route path="users" element={<Users Items={users}/>}/>
<Route path="/Panel" element={<Panel/>}/>
</Routes>

 <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>{
  navigate("/Panel")
 
}}>Panel</button>
<Users/>


</>
```

It's simple, But I want the Panel component to be a separate page instead of being part of the home page! And I don't want to show other components (in my project User component)

So I tried a trick: using showPages state to determine which page should be shown:

```
function App() {
 const users = useSelector(state => state.users)
const[showPages,setShowPages]=useState("users")
  useEffect(()=>{
    
    setShowPages("users")
    dispatch(getUsers())
  }
    
  ,[])
 return (<>
<button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>{
 setShowPages("panel")
 
}}>Panel</button>
 {showPages=="users" && ( <Users/> Items={users})} 
     
     {showPages=="Panel" && <Panel/>}
 </>
```

Now when  I click the Panel button, I can see Panel page as a separate page, But guess what: I missed back button of the browser! I also don't want to use html-based project and use react in it.

Is it possible to create non spa website using pure react? or I should create project without react and use react in it.

Comment: have you tried `nextjs`?

Comment: It sounds like you want different views rather than different pages. You might try [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/).

Comment: What you are looking for is the concept of routing (to direct a user to a specific page depending on the path). You don't need to reinvent the wheel from scratch, but use any existing solutions like what comes with NextJS, or React Router or React Router DOM. 

Also, single page application (SPA) does not mean it's just one page all the time. It means that there's just one wrapper, but you can have as many pages or complex components in it as you want.

Comment: @Heartbit no. I just hear about  next.js for SSR .But if it is useful , I try to learn it.

Comment: @AmruthPillai  Tnx react-router is ok. But what if I want to change wrapper and header and footer completely? In other words I want to see completely different page when I click the button.

Comment: @jsejcksn I already use react-router But I want  to see completely different page when I click the button

Comment: "Using *only* ReactJS"?? What do you mean by that? Anyways, if I understood you correctly, you might want to try NextJS or Remix.

Comment: @code Maybe it was better to say "Using react and react-router"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way. I created a new component named Home and I put User component and panel button in it. Rather than rendering home component in App component, I made Home component home page by routing:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home Items={users}/>}/>
```

I also routed Panel component in App component

```
<Route path="/Panel" element={<Panel/>}/>
```

Now here is my App component:

```
function App() {
const users = useSelector(state => state.users)
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const getUsers=()=>{
        // async action using redux-thunk
        return async function(dispatch){
            try{
            
            dispatch(GetUserRequest())
             const response= await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
             
            
             dispatch(GetUserSuccess(response.data.data))
            }
            catch(er){
                dispatch(GetUserFail(er))
               
            }
        }
    }
useEffect(()=>{
    
   
    dispatch(getUsers())
 }
    
  ,[])
return(<>
<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<Home Items={users}/>}/>
<Route path="/Panel" element={<Panel/>}/>
</Routes>
</>)
}
```

And here is Home component:

```
const Home = (props) => {
  return ( <>
<button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>{
  navigate("/Panel")
 
}}>Panel</button>
 <Users Items={props.Items}/>

</>
}
```

Now when I click Panel button I see Panel component as a separate page (non-spa).
You can also use child route and outlet if you want to have semi spa site(
for example if you want to render some components in home page and render others as separate pages
)

Answer (score 0):

I think It would be better to learn Framework those uses React.
Because React is not SEO Friendly. It had not any Server Side Rendering or Static Server Generation. It only provides Client Side Fetching and Rendering.

You can also Try React Router. But At some point, you would feel Hard to Maintain Routes with React Router.

If you want to Learn framework which uses React, You can try RemixJS.

Comment: ok but what about next.js?

Comment: There are a lot of framework built on top of React which is very SEO friendly like Gatsby and Next.js, your statement here is untrue.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Here I  just recommend Framework. I know Nextjs , Gatsby.

Comment: @AjayRaja Next.js and Gatsby.js just makes it easier to deal with SSR and SSG for react, this can absolutely be achieved using pure react as well.  check this link https://blog.jakoblind.no/getting-started-react-ssr it gives a good insight on how to deal with SSR using just react-js. However it is not easy to implement SSR using just plain reactjs